# Clone GitHub Repository and Merge All Pull Requests

Tags: git, github

Here is the repository I am looking to use - https://github.com/Sumi-Interactive/SIAlertView

What is the best way to clone this GitHub repository and merge all of the 36 open pull requests on that repository into the one I have just cloned?

Comment: Do you mean how do you *automate* this?

Comment: Do you own this GitHub repo?

Comment: No to both questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would kind of achieve what you want. Clone the remote, configure fetching of pull requests and then merge each of the PR branches.

However, there are conflicts between the branches. They are changing the same files in different ways. So merging all of them together is not a trivial task. And thus the script fails.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

git clone https://github.com/Sumi-Interactive/SIAlertView
cd SIAlertView

git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"
git fetch

for branch in $(git branch -r); do
    [[ $branch =~ origin/pr/ ]] && git merge $branch
done
```

Comment: Automatically accepting pull requests is a very bad practice. It defeats the point of a PR.

Comment: This works out well, the files with the conflict I don't need anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: This merges *all* pull requests, even ones that have been closed!

Comment: Changing `remote.origin.fetch` is unnecessary. You can just pull branches directly as `pull/*/head`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice how would you do that exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to automate it in a script, but `git fetch origin pull/###/head` works without changing `remote.origin.fetch`. (Replace `###` with an actual PR number.) I have been trying to figure out how to fetch all branches of this form, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Go through them, review them, and if it passes review click the merge button. If it doesn't comment and either fix it yourself or wait for the contributor to fix it.

You don't want to automate this, the point of having a PR is someone reviews it. If you automate acceptance it defeats the point. If you don't want to review PRs then skip them entirely and give contributors permission to push to master (probably not a great idea).

You don't appear to have [Continuous Integration Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) of the PRs, so you're not even sure the PRs work. Even if they work individually there's no guarantee they'll all work once smashed together. `master` will be a mess.

And with 36 simultaneous PRs there's a very good chance blindly merging all of them will cause conflicts (or worse, silently overwrite each other's changes). You need to integrate them intelligently.

And now that you've advertised your project is blindly accepting PRs, it's very easy for a malicious attacker to insert malware into your project.

What would be better is to find a few more people to help out with review and integration. This can be unofficial, just ask some people to comment on the PRs, or [you can use Github's review process](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/).

Comment: Since they want to clone the GitHub repo, I believe that the OP does not have any privileges in it so cannot merge the PRs.

Comment: I am not the owner of the repository.  I don't care about all that, I just want to get it up to date on my own and then I'll fix it.

Comment: @MikeDeluca You don't have to merge their PRs to get up to date to contribute to a project. It's a bad idea because you'll now be divergent from what everyone else is using and you don't know which PRs will be accepted or with what modifications. Fork the repo, clone it, and go. If you really want the PRs to look at locally you can use Harald's technique of fetching them and examining them, but don't blindly merge them! Stop at `git fetch`. [Or follow this procedure](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/).